# Asp.Net core library add

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am working on a simple project, where I have a asp.net core library named "BusinessApiClient" version-1.6 and have a web application project named "MyWebProject". I want to add "BusinessApiClient" in "MyWebProject" as reference. But my problem is its always showing error in reference list.

[image]

Project.json :

[image]

Don't know why its showing error !!!
Hope will get any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version 1.6 ? In a ASP.NET Core library project, the version is .NETCoreApp 1.0 or .NETCoreApp 1.1. If you have a .NET Core web app in version 1.0, your ASP.NET Core library have to target the framework .NETCoreApp 1.0, and it will works.

Comment: Can you show your class library properties ? Cause even if you are using a .NET standard class library in version 1.6, it has to work

Comment: @Adrien bro, library version is 1.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own nuget packages of your Businessapi client.

More information :

[Nuget info](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)

+

Than you can put that nuget package in a local folder and use that as a feed: [More info](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Goodluck!